# Scipy optimize.fmin wrong return values

Tags: python, scipy, python-3.4

I am currently using `scipy.optimize.fmin()` function and I am experiencing a problem with it. When I look at the documentation it says:

Returns:

```
    xopt : ndarray
        Parameter that minimizes function.

    fopt : float
        Value of function at minimum: fopt = func(xopt).

    iter : int
        Number of iterations performed.

    funcalls : int
        Number of function calls made.

    warnflag : int
        1 : Maximum number of function evaluations made. 2 : Maximum number of iterations reached.

    allvecs : list
        Solution at each iteration.
```

But when I try this:

`res, min = opt.fmin(optim, self._params, (param_optim, self._paramsIni, Qmes, critere_efficacite, self, codeBV, interval), maxiter=5)`

I get this error:

`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Anyone has an idea why? I mean is the documention wrong (I guess not) or am I doing something wrong? I am using scipy 0.19 and Python34

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The documentation you stated shows you the function returns *six* values, yet you assign it to two variables.

Comment: I tried `res, min, a, b, c, d = opt.fmin(optim, self._params, (param_optim, self._paramsIni, Qmes, critere_efficacite, self, codeBV, interval), maxiter=5)`, it does not work either.

Comment: The only one that is working is `res = opt.fmin(optim, self._params, (param_optim, self._paramsIni, Qmes, critere_efficacite, self, codeBV, interval), maxiter=5)` but I really need this second returned value.

Comment: Unfortunately, `fmin` is one of those scipy functions that changes its output depending on its output. The relevant input parameter from the documentation: "full_output : bool, optional.  Set to True if fopt and warnflag outputs are desired." So `fmin` outputs either 1 value, or 6 values, depending on the `full_output` input flag.

Comment: Thank you Evert! It solved my problem. I was wondering what was this `full_output` flag for, as it was not displaying anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be slightly more exact: The function returns either a tuple of 6 values (

> full_output : bool, optional
>       Set to True if fopt and warnflag outputs are desired.

) or one (if it is left at `False` which is the default). If you want to have only the second value of the full output, I recommend you set `full_output=True` and pattern-match as suggested in the comments. Alternativly you can store the result in one tuple `res = opt.fmin(<your arguments>)` and then access `r=res[0] min=res[1]`.